# passport bad request node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, passport.js

i am using passport authentication, so when I trying to sign up or register, so I enter my email password and click to send data its shows a bad request. and my data save to DB but I am render where I want .

here is my sign up route code w passport

a

```
pp.post("/sign-up",(req,res)=>{

    
    User.register({ username: req.body.email }, req.body.password, (err, user) => {
        console.log(user)
        console.log(err)
        if (err) {
           res.send("err")
        } else {
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () => {
                res.redirect("/compose");
            })
            
        }
    })
 
});
```

here is that code, that page I want to render after signup

```
 app.get("/compose" ,(req,res)=>{
    console.log('here')
   if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.render("compose")
   }else{
       res.redirect('/sign')
   }
    
});
```

here is image ,what I am seeing
[image]

Comment: same as the first problem I pointed out in your previous question  - look at my second comment ... `passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () => { res.redirect("/compose"); })` is completely wrong ... `passport.authenticate("local", (req, res) => { res.redirect("/compose");})` is what you want

Comment: thanks, sir, when I am using your code so my page continuously reloading and  not render to /compose, I have spent my whole day but code is not fix

Comment: `when I am using your code` you aren't using my code - you're using your code, which is wrong

Comment: sir, please do correct my code.

Comment: sir, you are saying this is correct syntax passport.authenticate("local", (req, res) => { res.redirect("/compose");})

Comment: Dude, I had zero knowledge of passport.js before responding to your first question about it ... I read the documentation ... and here we are - yes, I am saying that is correct syntax, is soemthign wrong with it? I'm not saying that's how to use it though - because ... I may have mentioned, I read the documentation

Comment: ok thanks, sir, you gave me you good time. for solving this problem.

Comment: I haven't solved anything ... http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/ shows you how to use the function